# Is there a way to make the code work with "import"?

Tags: python

I found out a code from a script that prevented it to be opened with `import`

```
def begin(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)

    init_maze()
    generate_maze()
    mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.setupterm()
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.curs_set(False)
    stdscr.keypad(True)

    cols = curses.tigetnum('cols')
    lines = curses.tigetnum('lines')
    while width < cols and height + 5 < lines:
        curses.wrapper(begin)
        width += 10
        height += 6
```

The main one is `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Can anyone tell me how to make so that the game can works without `if __name__ == '__main__':` and works with `import`?

EDIT: If I delete `if __name__ == '__main__':`, the script doesn't work anymore

Comment: JACKDANIELS777 where???

Comment: There is nothing in that script that prevents it from being ``import``'ed – provided it contains the code necessary to make it work as claimed. Please [edit] your question to clarify the problem.

Comment: If you’re just trying to run the script, you could run `python myscript.py`. To use an import, you would have to organize the code in functions/clases. You could then call `script.function()` after importing.

Comment: What script doesn't work (this one, or the one you've imported into)? What errors are you getting? Do you understand what the if statement does?

Comment: @OneCricketeer It works perfectly, it's just that when I do "import file.py" it doesn't import it. Altho, it works when I open it manually

Comment: ``import`` works via *module* name, not *file* name. The correct way would be ``import file``, not ``import file.py``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I always do it WITHOUT .py, I write import file. Not import file.py

Comment: @SmoggyLeaf And that is exactly why you are being asked to [edit] your question to reflect what *exactly* must be done to reproduce what *exact* problem. We do not know which parts are actually missing, omitted, or misrepresented. Please see the [mcve] page how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your module is in the same directory as the code which you are trying to import the module to, I believe this should work:

```py
def begin(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)

    init_maze()
    generate_maze()
    mainloop()

def main():
    curses.setupterm()
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.curs_set(False)
    stdscr.keypad(True)

    cols = curses.tigetnum('cols')
    lines = curses.tigetnum('lines')
    while width < cols and height + 5 < lines:
        curses.wrapper(begin)
        width += 10
        height += 6

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

From the script which you import this from, you could then do this:

```py
import my_script.py

my_script.main()
```

Comment: Also it doesn't have to be in the same directory, but it has to be in a directory which is included in the paths variable that python is going to look through for libraries to import

Comment: @user14518362 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: An interesting thing to know is that you can add path variables either permanently for python or within your code temporarily

Comment: @user14518362 it is in the same directory

Comment: @SmoggyLeaf What he's trying to say is that you can import it, but it's not going to do anything if it's in the __name__ == '__main'__ if.

you should look into what this if statement does, here's a related question that should explain it to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do